# Reference about infinite dimensional matrix

Tags: matrices, reference-request

I want some knowledge about infinite dimensional matrix. The infinite dimensional means that the matrix has infinite rows and columns. I just find some paper about the infinite matrix, but seemly, there is not a systematic discussion about it. What book I should read?

Comment: Richard G. Cooke's [Infinite matrices & sequence spaces](https://www.amazon.com/Infinite-Matrices-Sequence-Spaces-Mathematics/dp/048678083X)?